# I uploaded a video to Google Cloud Storage via AppEngine. What's the most efficient way to serve it?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Unlike images, there isn't an API like images.get_serving_url() for serving image blob. For things other than images, should we just set up a download handler and use send_blob() like we would for objects in BlobStorage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [ACL](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol) your object to public-read and then serve it directly from [GCS](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris).

As an example you can have a look at a quick app I wrote to test serving audio and video from GCS and blobstore -> [audio-test.appspot.com](http://audio-test.appspot.com). [This](http://audio-test.appspot.com/render_ogg) link serves the file using a BlobstoreDownloadHandler while [this](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/sjl-test/song.ogg) link serves the same file direct from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks, Stuart! How did you extract the GCS url (i.e. http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/sjl-test/song.ogg)? I am able to get file_info.gs_object_name (i.e. /gs/some_bucket/fake-ODFhNjhmYjk5MDc2YTRkYzM1ZmVmYjJlZTBmYzRiNzQ=
) from BlobstoreUploadHandler.

Comment: gs_object_name should be the correct name of the uploaded file, IIRC.

Comment: To serve directly from GCS, the file would have to be public. However, files uploaded using blobstore.create_upload_url() seem to ignore the default acl.txt (w/ public-read) I set on the bucket and the files are kept private. Is it expected?

Comment: Also, from performance and cost standpoints, is it better to serve directly from GCS?

Comment: - AFAIK blobs uploaded via GAE will be private by default and you will need to manually ACL them public once they have been uploaded.

Comment: For the cost/performance thing - As you don't need an instance to serve the content then you're only up for bandwidth charges if you serve from GCS. The performance should be comparable in terms of download speed, but some browsers deal much better with non chunked transfers (which was the point of the test app). If you're objects are public I would serve them from GCS.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. Wrote up a feature request for setting ACL for blobstore.create_upload_url(): http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9107

Comment: @StuartLangley Could you pl share your python code for this app (serving GCS stored video) ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, you cannot create a serving url for an usual blob in the `BlobStore`, so the `BlobstoreDownloadHandler` would be the appropriate solution in your case. Probably the only feasible solution.