# Is there any way to serve streaming video with limited access authority using App Engine and Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

As the title says, is there any way to do something like user logs in, and he/she can watch his/her own videos?

What I thought was to upload a video to Cloud Storage, make its access control to public, and the webpage uses something like "iframe" to stream with the video url. But it couldn't accomplish the "limited access authority".

Btw, I found a reference link which does the above paragraph, but didn't solve my question.
[[I uploaded a video to Google Cloud Storage via AppEngine. What's the most efficient way to serve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694735/i-uploaded-a-video-to-google-cloud-storage-via-appengine-whats-the-most-effici][1])

Comment: If you authenticate the user on your side, you can use [Signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) to protect access.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One more question is, say, I authorize http://abc/def for ten minutes. In that ten minutes, technically speaking, everybody can access the url, right?

Comment: Yes, but the URL is a very long, opaque identifier. It is intractable to guess it.

Comment: @jterrace, thanks again for your reply. I tried the "Signed URL" and it worked as I expected in the perspective of access control (it could access, say, in ten minutes.) My current question is "how to generate the signed url in the server side?" I will post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the right answer here is to use [Signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs). This allows you to authenticate the user on your own and then provide them with a short-lived, long, opaque URL that provides access to the video.